# MobileSingleStickControl Elements Disabled Unity

Tags: unity, assets

I cloned my Unity project on other system. Elements attached to canvas(a prefab) are disabled and when I select an element in inspector, for example **Background** (shown in screenshot) it is showing weird stuff.

[image]

[image]

I suspect that some file has not been pushed that contains data related to assets, since inspector is showing improper values. For example; Rect Transform showing instance ID instead of showing X, Y value (please refer screenshot).

Please suggest what can be missing in project that hasn't been pushed or loaded properly by Unity? Thanks.

**Note:** I am using Unity v5.0.1. Cloned project made in Windows onto my mac system.

## EDIT

I upgraded unity. Now elements are similarly disabled in prefab in my original project with normal inspector mode, displaying correct components and values. See screenshot below. No element is rendering and canvas is showing empty like the first screenshot.

[image]

Comment: well blue in the inspector means prefab. Perhaps you did not clone some prefabs or something. Try exporting them as a package and then importing the package to the new project

Comment: I think Uri is right here, your prefabs are possibly missing or corrupted.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is prefab. I checked original prefab. It has elements disabled too, but inspector is displaying normal values. Is there any proper way required to use prefabs? Why can it be corrupted?

Comment: Prefabs tend to do that. From your original project select the prefab. Then right click and select export package. Make sure the include dependencies checkmark is selected. Then export the package and import it to the new project and your prefabs should be fine and dandy.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try your suggestion in few hours after getting back to home.

Comment: The "Instance ID" information is shown because you're using the Debug inspector. Click the hamburger menu in the top right (the three horizontal lines next to the lock icon) to switch back to the normal inspector instead of the debug mode.

Comment: @UriPopov Sorry for late reply. I was busy in some other tasks. I upgraded my unity version and facing same issue in the original project too now. My query was regarding cloned project from git. It was same project, just cloned. Still do I need to export prefab and use again?

Comment: Now prefab components are disabled in original project as well

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for reply. It is possible. But why elements disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watched starting minutes of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGYObojmkO4). And understand why elements were disabled default. It was because default platform in Build Settings selected was **Web Player** instead of some mobile platform. So I switched to **Android Platform** and all the child elements were enabled again. Please also make sure that **Mobile Input** is *enable* in Menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your prefab icons are white boxes it means they're corrupted. The best option is to retrieve and older working copy from your version control system.